# Admin create user, User pick their Password Devise gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, devise-confirmable, devise-async

How to do this scenerio: Using Device Gem Rails

Admin will create a user, then
User receive the email,

User open the email and update the password and his personal info. then he login his dashboard

Comment: I think https://github.com/scambra/devise_invitable will do this

Comment: Thanks, Devise_invitable gem helped me.